# Keychain Access iOS Issue

Tags: ios, keychain

having problems accessing keychain on iOS.

```
    CFMutableDictionaryRef query = CFDictionaryCreateMutable( nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr );
    CFDictionaryAddValue( query, kSecClass, kSecClassGenericPassword );
    CFDictionaryAddValue( query, kSecAttrService, str_service );
    CFDictionaryAddValue( query, kSecAttrAccount, str_account );
    CFDictionaryAddValue( query, kSecAttrAccessible, kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked );
    CFDictionaryAddValue( query, kSecValueData, str_date );

    const auto res = SecItemAdd( query, nullptr );
```

This code works fine on Mac and works fine on iOS if I remove the str_data attribute. However, once I try to add the data, I get a return of the dreaded -50 error code.

The 3 str_ parameters are all CFStrings.

Any pointers welcome, thx.

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers to your questions. I notice this question includes an answer from a previous question you asked on this but still have not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

`kSecValueData` needs to be `CFDataRef` not a `CFStringRef`. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecvaluedata?language=objc